# Importing Text from local json file in React native

Tags: react-native

I am wondering how the common way is to import a huge text to a View. In my case i am developing a React Native App for Android and iOS, and on one of my Views i want to present the "Terms of Use" document. Now when i just import/copy paste it into a Text Component it just can´t be the right solution, especially when i need to use localization to present the needed language. How would i "import" this Text-Block so it is nice formatted and i don´t need to put everything into my View:

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}> |JSON - Text-file, with about 600 words -> Terms of Use document |</Text>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use:

```
import file from './config/TermsAndCondition.json';
```

then you can treat it as a javascript object:

```
file.description
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I did the same but in my case the object running 3 times in console. ?

Answer (score 5):

I'd to it as JSON, especially if you need to bring some other (meta)data with the text. Where `fetch(url)` is called on `componentWillMount` and `<Text>{this.state.hugeText}</Text>` component is populated:

As a concept:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    hugeText: ''
  };
}

componentWillMount() {
  fetch('myText.json')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      hugeText: data.something
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried `fetch` but it didn't work (wasn't able to find the file).

I tried this instead, and it worked:

```
// at top of file
var jsonData = require('./myfile.json');


// inside component definition
render() {
    let deepProp = jsonData.whatever;
}
```