# How can I bundle .proto files with a React Native app?

Tags: react-native, protocol-buffers, react-native-fs

I am trying to build an app to communicate with embedded devices using Protocol Buffers with protobuf.js

I want to load the content of .proto files at runtime. The files are pulled from a shared repo and I want to have them bundled with the app at build time.

I know I can read files with RNFS from DocumentDirectoryPath, but how do I tell React Native to put them there when building the app? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably a duplicate of [In React Native how do you bundle a text file and read it's value at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317440/in-react-native-how-do-you-bundle-a-text-file-and-read-its-value-at-runtime).

if you put anything inside android/app/src/main/assets folder it will be in your final .apk file, and you can read it with

```
RNFS.readFileAssets
```

Also there are more customized libraries like [This one](https://github.com/IgorBelyayev/React-Native-Local-Resource)

Comment: Thank you, that library is exactly what I was looking for!